# VBA recursive function doesn't work

Tags: function, vba, excel

I want to write this function from here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721494/what-is-the-value-of-this-game

I have written the following, but it doesn't work.

```
 Function value(b As Integer, r As Integer)

If r = 0 Then
  value = 0
End If

If b = 0 And r > 0 Then
  value = r
End If

 If (b < 0 Or r <= 0) Then
   value = 0
 End If

value(b, r) = (b / (b + r)) * (-1 + value(b - 1, r)) + (r / (b + r)) * (1 + value(b, r-1 ))

End Function
```

Can someone explain why it doesn't work, I am very new to VBA and programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Function gameValue(b As Integer, r As Integer)
    If b < 0 Or r <= 0 Then
      gameValue = 0
      Exit Function
    End If

    If b = 0 And r > 0 Then
      gameValue = r
      Exit Function
    End If

    gameValue = (b / (b + r)) * (-1 + gameValue(b - 1, r)) + (r / (b + r)) * (1 + gameValue(b, r - 1))
End Function
```

Note that I've changed function name from `value` to `gameValue`. The reason is because there is built-in excel worksheet function with name `VALUE`